# Как вывести все значения при связке 2 таблиц в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Есть 2 таблицы `table_links` и `user`

В моделе UserForm

```
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }

    public function getTableLinksForm()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TableLinksForm::className(), ['id' => 'manager_id']);
    }
```

В моделе TableLinksForm

```
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'table_links';
}

public function getUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['manager_id' => 'id']);
}
```

В контроллере

```
$users = User::findOne(2);
$username = $users->username;
```

Выводит лишь 1 пользователя

Как мне вывести нескольких пользователей?

Пробовал так = не хочет

```
$users = User::findOne([2,4]);
$username = $users->username;
```

Comment: "Пробовал так = не хочет" ....  а значение find **ONE**  вам ни о чём не говорит?  или в доках https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/db-active-record#querying-data   не написано ничего?

Comment: Пробовал и Many , ошибку выдаёт

Comment: One тоже убирал оставлял только find

Comment: ага. отлично. а в доках как написано  в разделе "получение данных"?

Comment: Вот, пишу по докам

`$customers = User::find()->indexBy('id')->all();`

И пишет NULL
Хотя в таблице есть с таким id пользователь

Comment: что в доках написано по поводу indexBy? читали? Условие задаётся по-другому

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136583/discussion-between-dmitrii-mv4-and--).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Алексей, спасибо!

Теперь работает связь с 2мя таблицами

Вывел в контроллере

```
$select_manager_attached = User::find()
->select('user.*')
->leftJoin('table_links', '`table_links`.`id_manager` = `user`.`id`')
->where(['table_links.id_manager' => [2,4]])
->all();
```

Далее подставил id который у меня подтягивается при редактировании в контроллере

```
$select_manager_attached = User::find()
->select('user.*')
->leftJoin('table_links', '`table_links`.`id_manager` = `user`.`id`')
->where(['table_links.id_blogger' => $id])
->all();
```

Функции `getUser` и `getTableLinksForm` не понадобились больше